# obtener valor de input generado dinamicamente por jquery

Tags: jquery, html5

Amigos como podria tomar el valor de input generado dinamicamente por jquery, vi ejemplos que ponen contenedores div pero no funciona, su ayuda por facvor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acceder a el contenido de tu input por medio de su id, tendrías que cambiar tu selector por:

```
$("#txtPasswordCliente").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema ocurre cuando le estás dando la instrucción de detectar el click cuando carga el documento, como tu botón es dinámico cuando carga el documento por primera aún no existe dicho elemento y por eso no lo encuentra.

En lugar de colocar la instrucción dentro del document ready ponla de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnIniciarSesion", function(){

    #codigo de tu click

});
```

Y platicanos si te funcionó.

PD. Para futuras ocasiones coloca tu código en texto y no en imagen. Como dicen por ahí "Ayúdame a ayudarte"

Comment: Gracias Marco Izaguirre, lo que hize fue oculta el input y volverlo a mostrar